# Excel: Omit minus sign when formatting cell

Tags: excel

First of all, I realize that there are threads like this already, but I cannot get the examples I've seen to work. What I want to accomplish is that a cell value should be presented as "x,xx" and in red color if the value is higher than 0, and otherwise in Color 14.

For instance, if this formatting would be used on

```
0,05-0,03
```

It would return (in red):

```
0,02
```

What I have done is to format the cell as:

```
[Red][>0]0,##;[Color14][<=0]0,##;
```

but it prints out a minus sign for values less than or equal to 0, which I do not want. Changing to:

```
[Red][>0]0,##;[Color14][<=0]0.##;
```

Omits the minus sign, as I want, but it makes the cell red which is not intended.

I've also tried a numerous combinations of ",", "." and "#" but it just wont work as intended.

I hope anyone can shed some light into this.

EDIT Using "General" instead of "0,##" prints out many more decimals than desired.

EDIT2 I use a Swedish Excel and hence I translate the formulas to Swedish formulae. Perhaps of importance?

Comment: Sorry for being non-clear. What I meant with "presented as "x,xx"" is that I want to use "," as decimal delimiter and to use two decimals. 

I will use the formatting on a formula which is merely the difference between two numbers, in some places. The numbers are such that there is a possibility that the result (which I will use the formatting on) may have one integer proceeding the decimals, like x,xx or more than one, like xx,xx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.

```
<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>
```

So for your requirement no [conditions] are needed.

```
[Red]0,##;[Color14]0,##;[Color14]0,##
```

will suffice.

As for your further descriptions

```
[Red]0,00;[Color14]0,00;[Color14]0,00
```

may be better.

Comment: Thanks alot, I've read that earlier and written something in the lines of that. However when I use "0,##" it sometimes writes "0," but changing it to merely "0,00" gives the appropriate appearence, so thank you for making me realize that!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the value of the cell with formatting, only the appearance.
So if you want the cell value to actually be positive it is not possible to do this way.

If this is what you actually want to do, try `=ABS(A1)` (will have to be done in another cell)